# union object acts like a structure

Tags: c++, windows, performance, winapi, performancecounter

## UPDATE:

If you want to see the original manifestation of this problem read the "Original question" section.

In a nutshell: I was modifying a field of a C++ union object, but this had no effect on the rest of the fields and it behaved pretty much like a structure. For the solution: see my answer.

## Original question

**tl;dr: isn't `QueryPeformanceCounter` supposed to return its value in the `QuadPart` field of the provided `LONG_INTEGER` instead of `HighPart`/`LowPart`? I couldn't find anywhere that this is system specific, but so it seems to be.**

### Details

I am getting a peculiar behaviour from Windows's `QueryPeformanceCounter`. Consider this very simple use, following closely [Microsoft's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>

bool test()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start, end, freq;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)) {
        cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
        return false;
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    Sleep(1000);  // Simulate work

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    cout << "range: from " << start.QuadPart << " to " << end.QuadPart << endl;
    return true;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
range: from -3689348814741910324 to -3689348814741910324
```

This seems quite random, but it is not so. Adding the dumping function:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const LARGE_INTEGER& li) {
return os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << "["
    << "HP: 0x"   << std::setw( 8) << li.HighPart   << ", "
    << "LP: 0x"   << std::setw( 8) << li.LowPart    << ", "
    << "u.HP: 0x" << std::setw( 8) << li.u.HighPart << ", "
    << "u.LP: 0x" << std::setw( 8) << li.u.LowPart  << ", "
    << "QP: 0x"   << std::setw(16) << li.QuadPart   << "]"
    << std::dec << std::setfill(' ');
}
```

and changing the code to:

```
bool test()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start, end, freq;
    cout << "freq:" << endl;
    cout << freq << endl;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)) {
        cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
        return false;
    }
    cout << freq << endl;

    cout << "start:" << endl;
    cout << start << endl;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    cout << start << endl;

    Sleep(1000);  // Simulate work

    cout << "end:" << endl;
    cout << end << endl;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    cout << end << endl;

    cout << "range: from " << start.QuadPart << " to " << end.QuadPart << endl;
    return true;
}
```

yields the following output:

```
freq:
[HP: 0xcccccccc, LP: 0xcccccccc, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
[HP: 0x00000000, LP: 0x0025a801, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
start:
[HP: 0xcccccccc, LP: 0xcccccccc, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
[HP: 0x0000000a, LP: 0xa6b8ff15, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
end:
[HP: 0xcccccccc, LP: 0xcccccccc, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
[HP: 0x0000000a, LP: 0xa6dfb945, u.HP: 0xcccccccc, u.LP: 0xcccccccc, QP: 0xcccccccccccccccc]
range: from -3689348814741910324 to -3689348814741910324
```

Thus the cryptic value `-3689348814741910324` is nothing but the default uninitialized value for QuadPart: `0xcccccccccccccccc`. So calling QueryPerformanceCounter(&start); didn't update `QuadPart`, but `LowPart` and `HighPart` instead. From this it is obvious how to extract the actual return value of QueryPerformanceCounter as a LONGLONG:

```
// Extract the HighPart/LowPart pair from a LARGE_INTEGER as a LONGLONG.
LONGLONG odd_extract(LARGE_INTEGER li) {
    return (static_cast<LONGLONG>(li.HighPart) << 32) + li.LowPart;
}
```

Now substituting the last output in the test with:

```
cout << "range: from " << odd_extract(start) << " to " << odd_extract(end) << endl;
```

outputs

```
range: from 47158533369 to 47161073403
```

Finally, computing the elapsed time in seconds returns an expected value:

```
LONGLONG elapsed = odd_extract(end) - odd_extract(start);
double seconds = static_cast<double>(elapsed) / odd_extract(freq);
cout << "elapsed: " << seconds << " s" << endl;
```

outputs

```
elapsed: 1.02861 s
```

which is to be expected from Windows's inaccurate `Sleep()`.

**Now my question is this: isn't `QueryPeformanceCounter` supposed to return its value in the `QuadPart` field of the provided `LONG_INTEGER` instead of `HighPart`/`LowPart`? I couldn't find anywhere that this is system specific, but so it seems to be.**

### UPDATE 1

System: `64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise`

Compiler/IDE: `MVS 2010 v. 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel`

Definition of _LARGE_INTEGER in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\WinNT.h`:

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
#endif //MIDL_PASS
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

Still, it seems that despite that LARGE_INTEGER is a union it does not behave like one...

### UPDATE 2

It seems that I don't see this behaviour with a fresh solution/project. Perhaps there is another problem in the solution that I am trying to measure the performance of that causes this.

In any case, I still have no idea why this happens, so any suggestions on how to resolve it would be welcome, thanks!

Comment: LARGE_INTEGER is a union. QuadPart overlaps HighPart/LowPart, so I can't explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Are you using some non-standard structure packing (`#pragma pack` or similar)? Also, what compiler are you using, and what platform are you targeting? Have you inspected the variables in your debugger? Are they the same as those printed to standard output?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: I added an update with the definition of LARGE_INTEGER for my system. It does indeed seem to be a union, but not to behave like one...

@IInspectable: I don't know about `#pragma pack` so I assume I am not using it, haha (although it is possible, as I am working on a larger project that I inherited from others). See the update about the system. I first inspected the variables in the debugger, and then decided to print them out for clarity in my SO question, but yes - they are the same in the debugger.

Comment: With the MS example (after your typo fix), I get `Range from 31044870256 to 31047598565`, so I can't reproduce the issue you report using it.

Comment: @KenWhite: please see the second update.

Comment: @stanm please note, however, that what you are doing is undefined behavior. (it would be well-defined in C99, but not in C++ and C89.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: which part?

Comment: @stanm reading from an inactive union member.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ah, you're right, I was just hacking around trying to find a workaround. I guess I would use the `u` member if I really needed a stable workaround, but now that I know what the problem is, it is unnecessary.

Comment: -3689348814741910324 = 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC which means [you've accessed uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). You can also see a lot of 0xcccccccc in your output

Comment: @phuclv: cool, thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There was a

```
#define union   struct
```

in a header file of the project I was debugging.

I am crying.

Comment: Uhm... \*blank stare\* If you find out, why someone put this in a header file, I'd be interested to hear. You should probably also pass on the news to this guy: It is **illegal** to re-`#define` keywords in C++.

Comment: Seriously? Some kind of prank?

Comment: I wish compilers gave errors in general for macros not named with `SCREAMING_UGLY_UPPERCASE`. My condolences for this code.